# "No Persistence Unit Found" error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'txManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'CounterpartContacts' found
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'txManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'CounterpartContacts' found
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'CounterpartContacts' found
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [persistenceLayer.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'CounterpartContacts' found
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'CounterpartContacts' found
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:337)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.determinePersistenceUnitInfo(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:219)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:185)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:54)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:77)
    at com.apollo.counterpartcontacts.service.PersistenceManagerTest.beforeClass(PersistenceManagerTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:537)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:206)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1182)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:761)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:612)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:107)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CounterpartContacts">
        <jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/CounterpartContact</jta-data-source> 
        <class>com.counterpartcontacts.entity.AgentContact</class>
        <class>com.counterpartcontacts.entity.SecurityContact</class>
        <class>com.counterpartcontacts.entity.Bank</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my persistenceLayer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="persistenceManager" class="com.apollo.counterpartcontacts.service.PersistenceManager">
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<!--    <context:annotation-config />   -->

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="CounterpartContactDataSource" /> 
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CounterpartContacts" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The persistence.xml is located in src/META-INF, which is in the build path, so it should be found properly. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the persistence.xml is being copied over to the build directory (or something of that nature)?

Comment: @Jeremy How could I check this?

Comment: It depends. How are you building your application? Eclipse? Ant? Maven?

Comment: Check where the build path is set to with-in eclipse (probably classes) and look in the folder. Go to a file browser or command line to check. You should find the xml in that path

Comment: @chrislovecnm Yes, I see it in there.

Comment: is the file or the file and the folder?

Comment: Also you can set the location of the persistence.xml file with setPersistenceXmlLocation ... tryin to figure out if this is a classpath issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I usually place the persistence.xml in a resources folder /src/main/resouces/META-INF/persistence.xml because I do remember problems in the build not copying the resources to the output-directory.

I just had a look at our configuration and it looks a little different:

```
<!--
    - Drives transactions using local JPA APIs
-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" proxy-target-class="true" />

<!--
    Custom PersistenceUnitManager, that reads all persistence.xml files in the
    classpath and merges them to one single virtual persistence.xml.

    In order to operate properly, all persistence.xml have to define the same
    persistence unit name.
-->
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="de.cware.cweb.jpa.MergingPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<!--
    Creates a EntityManagerFactory for use with the Hibernate JPA provider and a simple
    in-memory data source populated with test data
-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${cweb.database.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${cweb.database.generate}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${cwb.home}/indexes</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">de.cware.cweb.jpa.QuotingNamingStrategy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.ManagedBasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${cweb.database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${cweb.database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${cweb.database.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${cweb.database.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${cweb.database.initial-pool-size}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${cweb.database.min-pool-size}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${cweb.database.max-pool-size}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="#{'${cweb.database.validationQuery}}'.length()==0?'':'${cweb.database.validationQuery}'}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="#{'${cweb.database.validationQuery}}'.length()==0?false:true}"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="#{'${cweb.database.validationQuery}}'.length()==0?false:true}"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="#{'${cweb.database.validationQuery}}'.length()==0?-1:10000}"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="#{'${cweb.database.validationQuery}}'.length()==0?-1:60000}"/>
    <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="#{ T(java.sql.Connection).TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED}"/>
</bean>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Chris

Comment: Ups ... just saw that the main difference was the usage of a custom PersistenceUnitManager ... I described that in my Wiki https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Multiple+persistence.xml+in+a+multi-module+application

Comment: Thank god I've found this post...META-INF should always be inside resources directory, so that it can work!

Answer (score 3):

- keep your persistence.xml in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
- remove hibernate conflicting libraries....
- remove hibernate - 3.2.0 jar if hibernate core is there

Answer (score 3):

place the persistence.xml in a resources folder `/src/main/resouces/META-INF/persistence.xml`  for me it's work this solution

Comment: Hm, I just spend hours and hours to find the error...I was rebuilding my entities all the time...

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen if you have a hibernate mapped class with relations with another non-mapped class, a solution is to check the relation item as @transient (hibernate will ignore it, use this just to check if this is the error, and later map the related class). Example:

```
@Entity
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

@Transient
private State state;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public State getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(State state) {
    this.state = state;
}

}
```

And this is the non-mapped class which may give the error:

```
public class State {

private String name;

}
```