# Spring Data @CreatedDate annotation doesn't work for me

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa

I am working on project where I use Spring Data. I wanted to fill in `creationTime` field using `@CreatedDate` annotation instead using method with `@PreUpdate` or `@PrePersist` annotation (doing it this way it works perfectly).  When I do it with `@CreatedDate` it just leaves this field blank. I use postgresql database. [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.auditing) is not very helpful.

Do you have any idea how can I fix it? Thank you!

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
@Entity
@Table(name = "software")
public class Software implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date creationTime;
    //...
}
```

My `applicationContext`:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="path.to.dao"/>


<context:component-scan base-package="path.to.dao"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="path.to.bean"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What are you using to persist the entity?

Comment: What I mean is are you using the `Session` directly or are you persisting through a Spring Data service?

Comment: I've got an interface `SoftwareRespository` which extends `JpaRepository<Software, Long>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may have been in a similar situation where I wanted the Spring Data JPA `@CreatedDate` annotation to work, but had no need for the user-level auditing that is otherwise described in their documentation.

To get the annotation-based auditing to work, I had to nonetheless add a class to my project that implemented `org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware`. This is odd because you don't actually seem to use the value returned from the `getCurrentAuditor()` method that you'll be implementing; mine just returns `null`.

```
public class NullAuditorBean implements AuditorAware {

    @Override
    public Object getCurrentAuditor() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I then needed to reference my "null object" `AuditorAware` implementation in an entry in my `applicationContext` to activate the JPA auditing. I had to make sure I did this before the line that specifies the `jpa:repositories`. This looks something like:

```
<bean id="auditorBean" class="your.package.subbed.here.NullAuditorBean"/>
<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorBean"/>
```

I also had to add an `orm.xml` file, and needed to formally reference it as a property of my `entityManagerFactory` bean, like so:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <value>META-INF/orm.xml</value>
</property>
```

Make sure this `META-INF/orm.xml` entry is stored with your compile output (mine is in my WAR under `WEB-INF/classes`.

That `orm.xml` file, for the record, contained some boilerplate, which can be found in the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764255/spring-data-jpa-auditing-feature-is-not-working-in-my-project).

It was a fair amount of work when I got this working. You may prefer your previous working solution!

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. In the future I'm going to add Spring Security to my project and then I will change my NullAuditor to something suitable.

Comment: orm.xml fixed my problem

Comment: For annonation based config. You can add @EnableJpaAuditing("nullAuditorBean")

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but still relevant.  For me the key was this, from [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.9.11.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html#mongo.auditing)

> Since Spring Data MongoDB 1.4 auditing can be enabled by annotating a configuration class with the @EnableMongoAuditing annotation.

For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
class Config {

  /**
   * Optional, depending on your needs
   */
  @Bean
  public AuditorAware<AuditableUser> myAuditorProvider() {
      return new AuditorAwareImpl();
  }
}
```

Or, in XML:

```
<mongo:auditing/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue, but wasn't able to get my head around it.
I have chosen to use Hibernate's [@CreationTimestamp](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-CreationTimestamp) instead, and it works like a charm!