# How can you make a created_at column generate the creation date-time automatically like an ID automatically gets created?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I currently have an Entity as below:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long productId;
    private String productImage;
    private String productTitle;
    private String productDescription;
    private Integer productPrice;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
```

Upon creation of this object, the value of createdAt and updatedAt shows null in the database and was wondering how I can implement code so that createdAt and updateAt automatically gets inserted?

My post method is as below:

```
@PostMapping("/products")
public ProductResponse createProduct(@Validated @RequestBody ProductForm productForm) {
    Product product = productForm.asProduct();
    Product createdProduct = productRepository.save(product);
    return new ProductResponse(createdProduct, "Product created");
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**JPA**

There isn't anything as convenient as annotating the Timestamp field directly but you could use the `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` annotations and with little effort achieve the same results.

**Hibernate**

- `@CreationTimestamp` - [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-CreationTimestamp)
- `@UpdateTimestamp` - [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-UpdateTimestamp)

**Spring Data JPA**

- `@CreatedDate` - [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.annotations)
- `@LastModifiedDate` - [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.annotations)

Comment: Will this set the system's time or the database system's time? I have the problem that sometimes the system time might be wrong and have no control over it, while the db system's time is correct (and more importantly unique)

Comment: For Spring Data JPA: Be aware to enable JPA auditing and add `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` to the entity. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56873616/6336728 for more information.

Answer (score 33):

Extend the following abstract class in your entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class DateAudit implements Serializable {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Don't forget to enable JPA Auditing feature using `@EnableJpaAuditing`

Read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html

Comment: in my case, i don't have any superclasses and base entities, and no `@EnableJpaAuditing` either, and `created_at` is set on every row insert and `updated_at` is set on every row update. is that because i'm using hibernate?

Comment: If you are not using Spring, then you are correct. `EnableJpaAuditing` is in the Spring package `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config`

Answer (score 25):

With the mix of @dimitrisli and @buddha answers, something pretty clean is

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

And now you all your entity can extend that class like so

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public UUID id;
    public String userName;
    public String email;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

*Note that you might not need `@Data` & `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations from lombok as it generate getter/setter*

Comment: if you want, you could move the id attribute to BaseEntity well

Comment: Be aware, `CreationTimestamp` & `UpdateTimestamp` are the hibernate annotations.

Answer (score 18):

You can create a BaseEntity. Each entity extends the BaseEntity. In the Base entity ,it will set the time automatically

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "deleted", columnDefinition = "Bit(1) default false")
    private boolean deleted = false;

    @Column(name = "DataChange_CreatedBy", nullable = false)
    private String dataChangeCreatedBy;

    @Column(name = "DataChange_CreatedTime", nullable = false)
    private Date dataChangeCreatedTime;

    @Column(name = "DataChange_LastModifiedBy")
    private String dataChangeLastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "DataChange_LastTime")
    private Date dataChangeLastModifiedTime;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() {
        if (this.dataChangeCreatedTime == null) dataChangeCreatedTime = new Date();
        if (this.dataChangeLastModifiedTime == null) dataChangeLastModifiedTime = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        this.dataChangeLastModifiedTime = new Date();
    }

    @PreRemove
    protected void preRemove() {
        this.dataChangeLastModifiedTime = new Date();
    }
}
```