# What would be a cleaner way to transfer data from a form object to an entity for an update method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Trying to refactor my code for the controller below:

```
 @PutMapping("products/{productId}")
    public ProductResponse updateProduct(@PathVariable("productId") Long productId, @RequestBody ProductForm productForm) {
        Optional<Product> foundProductOpt = productRepository.findById(productId);
        Product foundProduct = foundProductOpt.orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("productId" + productId + "not found."));

        //would like to refactor code below!!

        foundProduct.setProductTitle(productForm.getProductTitle());
        foundProduct.setProductPrice(productForm.getProductPrice());
        foundProduct.setProductDescription(productForm.getProductDescription());
        foundProduct.setProductImage(productForm.getProductImage());
        productRepository.save(foundProduct);

        return new ProductResponse(null, "product updated");
    }
```

Where I am simply transferring values from a form object into an entity object. Thought of creating a method but did not want to write a method in an entity so not sure what other solutions are out there.

As per request, below is my Product and form object. I would like to use a form object for validation and then have data transferred to the Product object.

Product.java

```
package com.assignment.restapi.domain;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long productId;
    private String productImage;
    private String productTitle;
    private String productDescription;
    private Integer productPrice;
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954812/how-can-you-make-a-created-at-column-generate-the-creation-date-time-automatical/49954965#49954965
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;

    // default constructor
    public Product() {

    }
    // parameterized constructor-User enetered value goes here to set the fields of the instantiated object.
    public Product(String productImage, String productTitle, String productDescription, Integer productPrice, Date createdAt) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
        this.productTitle = productTitle;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    // getter methods are used to retrieve a value from an object.
    // setter methods are used to set a new value to an object.
    public Long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    public String getProductTitle() {
        return productTitle;
    }

    public void setProductTitle(String productTitle) {
        this.productTitle = productTitle;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public Integer getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(@Min(value = 1, message = "値段は0以上の値を設定してください。") Integer productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

ProductForm.java

```
package com.assignment.restapi.web.view;

import com.assignment.restapi.domain.Product;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class ProductForm {

    String productImage;

    @NotBlank(message = "Product title is necessary")
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Product title has to be less than 100 letters")
    String productTitle;

    @Size(max = 500, message = "Product title has to be less than 500 letters")
    String productDescription;

    @Min(value = 1, message = "price has to have a value larger than 1")
    Integer productPrice;

    public ProductForm() {

    }

    public ProductForm(String productImage, String productTitle, String productDescription, Integer productPrice) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
        this.productTitle = productTitle;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    public String getProductTitle() {
        return productTitle;
    }

    public void setProductTitle(String productTitle) {
        this.productTitle = productTitle;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public Integer getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(Integer productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    //turns productForm into Product object.
    public Product convertToProduct() {
        //step by step debug mode, new object constructor function in Product.java gets called.
        //setter methods get called and values of the ProductForm object gets passed and becomes the new value of the Product object.
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductTitle(this.productTitle);
        product.setProductImage(this.productImage);
        product.setProductDescription(this.productDescription);
        product.setProductPrice(this.productPrice);
        return product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Apache [commons-beanutils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) ::**

This would work if you have same field names in both the classes.

```
@PutMapping("products/{productId}")
public ProductResponse updateProduct(@PathVariable("productId") Long productId, @RequestBody ProductForm productForm) {
    Optional<Product> foundProductOpt = productRepository.findById(productId);
    Product foundProduct = foundProductOpt.orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("productId" + productId + "not found."));
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(foundProduct, productForm); 
    productRepository.save(foundProduct);
    return new ProductResponse(null, "product updated");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but beanutils could not be used...is there anything I have to import?

Comment: You need to use **@Validated** annotation in addition to @RequestBody  to enable validation.  Checkout this snippet :: https://github.com/narayan-sambireddy/stackoverflow_49955529/blob/master/YourController.java

Comment: still unable as I get "cannot resolve symbol beanutils"

Comment: Oh! You need to add commons-beanutils dependency to your maven pom.xml file.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3

Comment: Check out this demo app which will give you more clarity on what needs to be included to get it working.

https://github.com/narayan-sambireddy/stackoverflow_49955529

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending `productId` in `@PathVariable` send it in body its self. Use `Product` in `@RequestBody` instead of `ProductForm`.

Also add validation in Product entity like `@NotNull,@NotBlank` and then use `@Valid` to validate Product request body.

And finally save the Product object. Since the product has `id` (product id), the repository's save() method will execute a update command on database.

So find code will be like this:

```
@PutMapping("/products")
public ProductResponse updateProduct(@Valid @RequestBody Product product) {
    Optional<Product> productOptional = productRepository.findById(product.getId());
    Product existingProduct = productOptional
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("productId" + product.getId() + "not found."));

    productRepository.save(product);
    return new ProductResponse(null, "product updated");
}
```

Comment: Would like to use the ProductForm object I already have for validation checking and not have to put validation on the Product object.

Comment: The reason why i have used `Product` in @RequestBody instead of `ProductForm`  is that, to avoid casting from `ProductForm` into `Product`.

Comment: Also if you want to hide specific fields from user you can use `@JsonProperty` .Example: `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` : Ignore field from request JSON

Comment: hmm I still would like to use a form object for validation and keep the entity with not validation annotations.

Comment: Can you add your `ProductForm` and `Product` class to your question. You can create a constructor in your Product class which takes `ProductForm` as parameter and will return Product object

Comment: @BrettFreeman **Don't** add additional information to an answer. Add it to your question where it belongs!

Answer (score 0):

You are really looking for a Mapper functionality. You can of course write it yourself (i.e. a Spring bean called `ProductEntityToDTOMapper` with methods `toEntity(dto)` and `toDto(entity)` or use a Java library for that: [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) is one that [supports Spring integration](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/spring-integration/) and another one is [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) that also provides [Spring integration](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection).