# Auto populate created_date, last_modified_date, created_by and last_modified_by in entity : Hibernate with JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate and JPA. I have several entities, each of which contains following four columns:

```
1. created_by
2. last_modified_by
3. created_date
4. last_modified_date
```

I would like these columns to get auto-populated while saving the associated entity.

Two sample entities are as follows:

**Entity 1:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "my_entity1")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class MyEntity1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Instant createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private String lastModifiedDate;
}
```

**Entity 2:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "my_entity2")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class MyEntity2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Instant createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private String lastModifiedDate;
}
```

In this context, I have gone through following posts: [How to autogenerate created or modified timestamp field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257709/how-to-autogenerate-created-or-modified-timestamp-field), [How can you make a created_at column generate the creation date-time automatically like an ID automatically gets created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954812/how-can-you-make-a-created-at-column-generate-the-creation-date-time-automatical).

I am getting how to capture the dates fields but I cannot understand how to capture created_by and last_modified_by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auditing Author using `AuditorAware` and `Spring Security`...

> To tell JPA about currently logged in user we will need to provide an
>   implementation of AuditorAware and override getCurrentAuditor()
>   method. And inside getCurrentAuditor() we will need to fetch currently
>   logged in user.

Like this:

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
        return "TestUser";
        // Can use Spring Security to return currently logged in user
        // return ((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername()
    }
}
```

Now enable jpa auditing by using `@EnableJpaAuditing`

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}
```

Look at [this](https://www.programmingmitra.com/2017/02/automatic-spring-data-jpa-auditing-saving-CreatedBy-createddate-lastmodifiedby-lastmodifieddate-automatically.html) to get more details....

Comment: I have a small doubt. Should I add setters for any of the fields of Auditable class ? I think, they would be populated on save/update of an entity which extends this class. It would not make sense to set them separately. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: if you use jpaauditing then use createby createdate. lastmodifiedby, lastmodified annotation only. ... u can just use lombok annotation for getter setter method.. no need to set new Date in getter setter method

Comment: @joy is this answer ok for you?