How should I save an entity in a Spring Boot application if I have added a not null column in the database?
For example I did:
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now();

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
...
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
...
}


Should I leave the createdAt field in the User entity as null when I save a new User to database? Will Hibernate automatically use the default value specified in the database? How I need to do the task correctly?
I tried to read the Hibernate manuals, but didn't find such cases. I don't understand the logic that Hibernate implements under the hood.

Maybe you can see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954812/how-can-you-make-a-created-at-column-generate-the-creation-date-time-automatical

Yes, it helps, but if my new column is not a time? For example is_active boolean not null default false, is there are a ways to tell Hibernate to use default value if user.isActive field is not set?

For whatever data type you have build a test case, run it, and see what the results are.

@CreatedDate()
@CurrentTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

If you use it this way, it will timestamp the creation date by default.

Yes, it helps, but if my new column is not a time? For example is_active boolean not null default false, is there are a ways to tell Hibernate to use default value if user.isActive field is not set?

I've never tried it before.

@ColumnDefault("false")
private boolean isActive;
you can try this
