# @MockBean on a MapStruct interface in a Spring @WebMvcTest does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, mapstruct

Given the following controller in a Spring Boot 3 application:

```java
// REST controller class
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bookings")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class BookingController {

    private final BookingMapper bookingMapper;
    private final BookingUseCase bookingUseCase;

    // controller methods...  
}

// @WebMvcTest
@WebMvcTest(controllers = BookingController.class)
class BookingControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    BookingUseCase bookingUseCase;

    @MockBean
    BookingMapper bookingMapper;

    // test methods
}
```

`CreditBookingMapper` is an interface for MapStruct:

```java
@Mapper
public interface BookingMapper {
    List<BookingResponse> mapToResponse(List<Booking> bookings);
    BookingResponse mapToResponse(Booking booking);
}
```

When running the controller tests, I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JPA metamodel must not be empty!`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606861/spring-boot-jpa-metamodel-must-not-be-empty-when-trying-to-run-junit-integrat