# JPA Envers @LastModifiedDate and @CreatedDate appear with null values in audit tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I am using JPA alongside hibernate envers to audit the entities. I want to all the entities have creation_date and modification_date table . As result , I created base class which contains the createdBy and lastModificationDate , and all the project entities extends this class .

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false , updatable = false)
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime creationDate;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "modification_date")
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime modificationDate;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "modified_by")
private String modifiedBy;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    this.creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    this.modificationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

}

however  ,@CreatedBy and @LastModificationDate are not working without setting their values inside  @PrePersist and @PreUpdate .

```
  @PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    this.creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    this.modificationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

}

if I commented @PreUpdate and @PrePersist annotation with their functions . they creationDate and modificationDate values will be null in original entities .

On the other hand , creationDate and modificationDate values are always with null in the audit table

Customer Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Builder
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String exmaple;

    private String example2;


}
```

AuditConfig

```
package com.sympl.customer.common.config.advice;

import com.sympl.customer.common.config.AuditorAwareImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider" , dateTimeProviderRef = "auditingDateTimeProvider")

public class AuditConfig {


    //...

    @Bean
    AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }

    //...

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I followed the [baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)  to setup audit

.I googled on similar issues , but their solution doesn't work with me

[@CreatedDate annotation does not work with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370709/createddate-annotation-does-not-work-with-mysql)

Comment: You are using LocalDateTime. Try long/Long or java.util.Date

Comment: @Omar Abo Elsoud try removing  `@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider" , dateTimeProviderRef = "auditingDateTimeProvider")` and the class where it exists and simple add `@EnableJpaAuditing` in the class that you have `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: I tried it . it doesn't work