# Auditing (@CreatedDate) does not work with Spring Boot Cassandra

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I have a simple entity where I want to let "createdDate" assigned automatically.

```
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

As also in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing) described, I have also added the annotation "**@EnableCassandraAuditing**" in my CassandraConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
@EnableCassandraAuditing
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
```

But It still does not work.. The entities are created with createdDate=null.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is missing to configure your `Auditable User` you need to create your own implementation since this does not work for it.

Answer (score 0):

Based the documentation says:

> We provide `@CreatedBy`, `@LastModifiedBy` to capture the user who created
>   or modified the entity as well as `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate`
>   to capture the point in time this happened.

I think the last one sentence means `capture the point in time this happened by some user.` Since I had the same `issue` a long time ago.

Then if you want to `@CreatedDate` annotation works then you need to give a current auditor. Should create your custom `Auditor Aware` by following way or simply the second one example.

**First Example:**

```
class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {

    public Optional<User> getCurrentAuditor() {

        return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                 .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                 .filter(Authentication::isAuthenticated)
                 .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
                 .map(User.class::cast);
    }
}
```

**Second Example:**

```
class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
         return Optional.of("CurrentUser");
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

I found an answer similar that you can check [@CreatedDate does not work answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483841/spring-data-createddate-annotation-doesnt-work-for-me/20508028#20508028)

Comment: "**In case you use either @CreatedBy or LastModifiedBy, the auditing infrastructure somehow needs to become aware of the current principal.**" You need those just for CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy annotations.. why should you need the user entity at all for "createdDate"?

Comment: Please remove `upvoted` @akcasoy since I had the same issue, when you want to  `@CreatedDate` annotation works then you need to give a current auditor. Based the documentation says:  `We provide @CreatedBy, @LastModifiedBy to capture the user who created or modified the entity as well as @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate to capture the point in time this happened.` I think the last one means capture the point in time this happened by some user.  you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20508028/10426557

Comment: sorry.. I really have tried but it does not work. it also makes no sense.. what if I have no security at all? What if i just want to save some entities from public endpoints where u don't have any user? And as I told before, documentation clearly points out "**In case you use either @CreatedBy or LastModifiedBy, the auditing infrastructure somehow needs to become aware of the current principal**"

Comment: Yes, I agree with that but I think it is more one issue related to how should work the `@CreatedDate` it is weird that doesn't not work. it would be great if you provide a small code example so that I can reproduce and help you as well :) @akcasoy

Comment: someone tried successfully? do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answer, you need an `AuditorAware` implementation for auditing to work. You can provide a dummy value.

However, there is another issue that can prevent `CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate` from working, which is that Spring might not be detecting that your entities are new and won't trigger the created by/date audit. This is because Spring detects whether an entity being saved is new or not by whether it's ID property is empty. However, Spring's Cassandra integration doesn't support automatic generation of IDs in a lot of cases which means that you often have to populate your entities' ID prior to passing it to your repository's `save` method. In these cases, the entities are not considered "new" and are not audited as "created."

You can check whether this is the issue by setting `modifyOnCreate` to `false` in `EnableCassandraAuditing` and changing the `@CreatedDate` to `@LastModifiedDate`. If you find that the field is now being populated when insert new entities, auditing is working but is just not recognizing new inserts.

To solve this problem, you have to find a different way to indicate that the entity being saved is new. These ways are documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#is-new-state-detection

I've had success doing the following:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table("my_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Persistable {
  @Column
  private UUID id;

  @Column
  private int someData;

  @Transient
  private boolean isNew = false;

  @Transient
  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return this.isNew;
  }
}
```

Then, in your service class, just set `isNew` to `false` when inserting a new entity.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyEntityService {
  MyEntityRepository repository;

  public void createEntity(int someData) {
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    MyEntity newEntity = new MyEntity();
    newEntity.setId(id);
    newEntity.setSomeData(someData);
    newEntity.setIsNew(true);
    repository.save(newEntity);
  }

  public void updateEntity(UUID id, int someData) {
    MyEntity previousEntity = repository.findById(id);
    previousEntity.setSomeData(someData);
    // previousEntity.getIsNew() should return false
    repository.save(previousEntity);
  }
}
```

See also the issue posted here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/1124